# Tomcat/TomEE/OpenEJB Datasource Connection to SQL Server - CPU Creep

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, apache-tomee, openejb

We are using TomEE (Tomcat with OpenEJB) to connect to a SQL Server database.  The connection works fine, but we are seeing odd CPU creeping issues.  The application runs and performs well for about 24 hours (SQL Server CPU at about 15%-20%), and then performance starts to suffer after that.  We check and the CPU is now at 60%.  If we shut down the running jobs (but leave Tomcat running), the CPU drop down to almost zero.  If we restart the processing, the CPU jumps back up immediately to the 60%.  If we stop the Tomcat instance and then restart, then the CPU usage on the SQL Server machine stays at its low usage for about 24 hours and then it begins to creep back up again.

I think that this must be due to the datasource configuration, but I'm not sure what changes we should make.  Can someone help out?  Here is the datasource configuration we are using:

```
<Resource id="Datasource" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
  accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed = false
  defaultAutoCommit = true
  ignoreDefaultValues = false
  initialSize = 0
  jdbcDriver = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  jdbcUrl = jdbc:sqlserver://{url}
  jtaManaged = true
  maxActive = 200
  maxIdle = 20
  maxOpenPreparedStatements = 0
  maxWaitTime = -1 millisecond
  minEvictableIdleTime = 30 minutes
  minIdle = 0
  numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
  password = {password}
  passwordCipher = Static3DES
  poolPreparedStatements = false
  testOnBorrow = true
  testOnReturn = false
  testWhileIdle = false
  timeBetweenEvictionRuns = -1 millisecond
  userName = {user}
  validationQuery = SELECT 1
</Resource>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Sorry if this is off-topic, but isn't datasource configuration within Tomcat considered code?  There are certainly other topic related to Tomcat configuration files here.